# How do I set a scope in a variable?

Tags: sql, variables, reporting-services, scope

I am re-creating a report to show the company's profit and losses, and I've added a second table with a new dataset. This has caused some issues with the 70+ variables which state I need to now add a scope.

I've tried adding a scope the way I've seen (by adding the data set after every `field!fieldname.value` but this doesn't seem to work, I've tried adding it in other places by guessing.

code from previous report:

```
    =Sum(CDbl(iif(Fields!TypeGroup.Value = "01",
    iif(Parameters!prmPeriod.Value = "Jan",iif(Fields!AccountType.Value = "R", Fields!JanMTDCurr.Value, Fields!JanMTDCurr.Value*-1),
    iif(Parameters!prmPeriod.Value = "Feb",iif(Fields!AccountType.Value = "R", Fields!FebMTDCurr.Value, Fields!FebMTDCurr.Value*-1),
    iif(Parameters!prmPeriod.Value = "Mar",iif(Fields!AccountType.Value = "R", Fields!MarMTDCurr.Value, Fields!MarMTDCurr.Value*-1),
    ...
    0)))))))))))),0)))
```

what I thought would work:

```
      =Sum(CDbl(iif(Fields!TypeGroup.Value,"MainReportData") = "01",
    iif((Parameters!prmPeriod.Value,"MainReportData") = "Jan", iif(Fields!AccountType.Value,"MainReportData") = "R", (Fields!JanMTDCurr.Value, "MainReportData"), (Fields!JanMTDCurr.Value,"MainReportData”)*-1),
    iif((Parameters!prmPeriod.Value,"MainReportData") = “Feb”, iif(Fields!AccountType.Value,"MainReportData") = "R", (Fields!FebMTDCurr.Value, "MainReportData"), (Fields!FebMTDCurr.Value,"MainReportData”)*-1), 
   ...      
   0)))))))))))),0)))
```

> Error message: the Variable expression for the report body uses an aggregate expression without a scope.

Comment: The quotes look different at the end of the 2nd and 3rd line, is this how they appear in code or just a typo/cut and paste issue?

Comment: Normally scopes are important for aggregations. Try using the scope in your `Sum()` function

Comment: @Strawberryshrub 
found the problem was with the brackets! thanks for helping you gave me a direction and that helped finding the brackets problem!